# Escaping backslash in a default Ansible filter with concatenated strings

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I've been struggling with the following problem:

I want to escape a backslash in a default filter to concatenate two vars. However Ansible throws the following error as expected (the backslash escapes the "):

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '"' at 41
```

I've been working around the problem but I'm wondering if it's possible to end up with a single backslash (\) in my string. Adding a backslash to escape the one in the concatenated string ends up giving me a double backslash. I know Ansible escapes the backslashes. The following playbook demonstrates the differences.

```yaml
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  vars:
    loop_var:
    - name: archive1
      path: '\\domain.com\archive1'
      targetpath: 'foobar'
      fallback: 'bla\bla\bla'
    - name: archive2
      path: '\\domain.com\archive2'
      fallback: 'bla\bla'

  tasks:
    - name: wanted output
      debug:
        msg: '{{ item.path }}\{{ item.fallback }}'
      loop: "{{ loop_var }}"
    - name: output default
      debug:
        msg: '{{ item.targetpath | default(item.path + "\\" + item.fallback) }}'
      loop: "{{ loop_var }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug, either in Jinja's lexer or in Ansible's Jinja integration. You can work around it by moving the `\` outside of the expression so that it doesn't trigger the bug:

```
    - name: output default
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.targetpath | default(item.path ~ bs ~ item.fallback) }}"
      loop: "{{ loop_var }}"
      vars:
        bs: \
```